# Looking for javascript library to save and restore html form, including restore from php's $_POST

Tags: javascript, php

I am looking for a library to restore html form fields (inputs, selects, checkboxes and everything else) state using javascript. State of the form should be previously saved in php's $_POST data or other serialized format.

I have html form and form validation in PHP.
PHP receives form fata on POST request and validates it, if user made a mistake - PHP displays this form again with restored values.
This problem appeares again when user wants to edit some previously saved data, and again we need to restore form state.

Usually I restore form state using PHP twig template like so:

```
<input type="text" name="anyname" value="{{anyname}}>
```

But I realised that there should be way to restore state using just one line of javascript code like so:

```
<script>
RestoreMyFormDataEasyWayIDontWantToWriteTwigTemplateAgain("formid",
    {{$POST | json_encode(constant('JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE')) | raw }});
</script>
```

Without touching html and fields values.

This should be already solved, but after hours of googlin I can't find this javascript library. Please help!

Comment: Why not use ajax so the form is submitted without refreshing the page

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Maybe `localStorage` ? Or some session storage in PHP  ? It's not really clear what you mean

Comment: If you're using jQuery there are a number of plugins for it, google "jquery save form state"

Comment: Well, I need to store form data in Mysql. Ajax is good, but how to show this form again in a day or two ? (with old saved values)